# ArticlesGrid where are Article.props? or How to reference props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties

In the ArticlesGrid example we have the following render function:

```
render () {    
  return this.state.articles && (
     <div className='articles'>
       { this.state.articles.map( function (article) {
         return <Article article={article} key={article.id} />;
       })}
     </div>
  );
}
```

So we have a component Article which has as one of it's props article which equals the object article, so far so good

Could someone explain what's going on with the next statement:

```
var Article = function({article}) {
```

why isn't it

```
var Article = function(this.props.article) {
```

??

in fact, when I try to console.log this.props I get undefined.  I thought Article was a component too.

UPDATE:  Here's the entire code:

```
class ArticlesGrid extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
     articles: []
  };
}

componentDidMount () {

  var url =
     'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?'
      + 'api-key=d68154fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc7f5';

   $.getJSON(url, function(data, status) {
      return this.setState({articles: this.parse(data)});
   }.bind(this));       
}

parse(results) {      
  if(!results || !results.response) return [];      
  var articles = results.response.docs;

  var parsedArticles = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < articles.length;i++){
     var article = articles[i];
     if (article.multimedia.find(this.isXL)) {

        parsedArticles.push({
           id: article._id,
           title: article.headline.main || 'Untitled',
           imageURL: article.multimedia.find(this.isXL).url || '#',
           webURL: article.web_url || '#'
        });
     }
  }     

  return parsedArticles;
}

isXL (image) {
  return image.subtype === 'xlarge';
}

render () {


  return this.state.articles && (
     <div className='articles'>
       { this.state.articles.map( function (article) {
         return <Article article={article} key={article.id} />;
       })}
     </div>
  );
}
}


var Article = function({article}) {
  var imgURL = 'https://static01.nyt.com/' + article.imageURL;

  return (
     <div className='article'>
        <a className='article-link' href={article.webURL}>
           <img className='article-image'
                title={article.title}
                src={imgURL} />
        </a>
     </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<ArticlesGrid/>,document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Where are these functions being called? Can you post code for the entire component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try to console.log this.props I get undefined. I thought
>   Article was a component too.

Yes `Article` is a component too but it is a [`functional component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). `props` to this are passed as argument to this function. So if you want to log props of this component then you can do it following way

```
var Article = function(props) {
  console.log(props)
  var imgURL = 'https://static01.nyt.com/' + article.imageURL;
```

> What is var Article = function({article}) {

This is called [`object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). It means that if an object is passed to this function then take `article` property of that object. So basically

`var Article = function({article}) {`

roughly means

```
var Article = function(props) {
   var article = props.article
   ...
```